# Play video from stream of data in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, video, websocket

I have an api with web socket connection and it return uint8 data type, it stream video data.
My problem is the video players in flutter doesn't accept stream of data.

They accept File, Network and Asset.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the Uint8List to a file.

If your target is only android and iOS you can use

```
File.fromRawPath(Uint8List uint8List);
```